# Encryption and Decryption when transmitting data

Tags: blockchain, encryption

If I was sending data to a smart contract, do I need to encrypt it before transmitting and decrypt it in the smart contract? Or is this done automatically?

Comment: Apologies if the question was not clear. I wanted to know if one has to encrypt the data before transmission in case of data corruption during transmission. I am not concerned about privacy as i know Ethereum is public and permissionless.

Comment: Encryption does not prevent data corruption. 
A hash signature, bundled with the data payload, can allow the receiver to verify the data contents. 
But no, there is no encryption needed.

Comment: @Bobby - Ah, okay, understood. I've removed my suggested duplicate flag.

Comment: @shane The question is about transaction data while on transit not when it is in the contract storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Communication at the p2p level are encrypted between the nodes.

Between your wallet and the node it depends on the wallet. Some wallets use https so the transactions are encrypted by that protocol.

Comment: I am playing around with web3.py to interact with smart contracts. Would it make sense to encrypt the data to ensure data integrity?

Comment: Your transaction data is signed with your private key so it cannot be manipulated easily while on transit.

Comment: yes this is what i wanted to know, signing the transaction data with the private key. But do we need to sign it explicitly or is this done 'under the hood'?

Comment: @Bobby All transactions have to be signed. If it explicit or implicit depends on the client/framework you are using to send transactions.

Comment: in the case of using web3.py, does one need to sign transactions explicitly?

Comment: @Bobby I have not used web3.py yet. In most frameworks it is implicit. Either you supply a wallet at the beginning, or connect to a client where the wallet is already unlocked (geth) or unlocked on demand (ie Metamask).

Answer (score 0):

If data get compromised, signature verification fails.

when Ethereum nodes receive transactions, they verify transactions using their signatures.

`signature = hashing_algorithm(transaction informations)`

If the signature does not match the transaction values, the transaction will become an invalid transaction, removed and not be saved in the transaction pool.

Comment: I am aware Ethereum is permisionless and I am not talking about privacy, I want to know if one has to encrypt it during transmission in case data gets compromised

Comment: understood, I've edited my answer.

Comment: yes this is what i wanted to know, signing the transaction data with the private key. But do we need to sign it explicitly or is this done 'under the hood'?

Comment: the signature is essential in the transaction. If we don't have a private key when we create a transaction, we can't attempt to create it. When we try to create a transaction, automatically signature is made from a private key. The public key generated from the private key is used for verifying the transaction. The public key is exposed to others.